# How to change MudBlazor ListItem selected color

Tags: blazor, theming, mudblazor

I would like to change the selected color (as well as hover color) of MudBlazor MudListItem. I've tried fiddling with the colors provided by Mudtheme, but nothing seems to do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It added with the last release. You look at this link.

https://mudblazor.com/components/list#color